# Efficient Execution of code

Tags: performance

```
       if (x > 5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

,and I have a single code expression :

```
  return (x > 5);
```

Which block of code will execute more efficiently?-Either the if-else block or a single Return Statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decent compiler will optimise the first version into the second one.

Without optimisation, the first version contains a branch (Jxx instruction in x86 assembly), which is slow:

```
cmp ecx, 5    ; assume ecx contains the value of x
jle 1f        ; assume x is signed
mov eax, 1
ret
1:
xor eax, eax
ret
```

The second version translates to a SETxx instruction in x86, which does not involve a branch, and would be faster:

```
xor eax, eax
cmp ecx, 5
setg al
ret
```